# How to properly encode a file in Polish in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to open the inflation data from the Polish Statistics Office.

The code below:

```
import pandas as pd
inflation_data_url = 'https://stat.gov.pl/download/gfx/portalinformacyjny/pl/defaultstronaopisowa/4741/1/1/miesieczne_wskazniki_cen_towarow_i_uslug_konsumpcyjnych_od_1982_roku.csv'
pd = pd.read_csv(inflation_data_url, sep=';', encoding="UTF-8")
print(pd.head())
```

Gives me the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 42: invalid continuation byte

If I try a different encoding:

```
import pandas as pd
inflation_data_url = 'https://stat.gov.pl/download/gfx/portalinformacyjny/pl/defaultstronaopisowa/4741/1/1/miesieczne_wskazniki_cen_towarow_i_uslug_konsumpcyjnych_od_1982_roku.csv'
pd = pd.read_csv(inflation_data_url, sep=';', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
print(pd.head())
```

I get no errors, but the encoding is clearly wrong, since "Wskaźnik cen towarów i usług konsumpcyjnych" is being decoded as "Wskaw i us³ug konsumpcyjnych".

How can I download this data in Python and open it so it displays proper characters?

Comment: any chance it's Windows-1250? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250. Looks like character B3 denotes "ł" in Windows-1250, but "³" in ISO-8859-1, so maybe...

Comment: It is, thanks! How would I figure this out next time in a similar situation?

Comment: Read the documentation that tells you what encoding the file is in. Perhaps look at the HTTP response headers, they *may* tell you as well. If all else fails, just play around with all possibly relevant encodings until you find the right one.

Comment: Generally, you just have to *know* the encoding ahead of time, or at least know what the alternatives are so you can, for example, note that the single byte `0x9f` is being used to encode ź, which should indicate which encoding is being used.

Comment: The `requests` module guessed `Windows-1250` when downloading that link (uses `chardet` module internally, I believe).  The headers just said the transfer encoding was `binary` and was no help.  Comparing the results from `Windows-1250` and `ISO-8859-2` the former looks correct: `Wskaźnik` vs. `Wskanik`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use encoding ISO-8859-**2** instead, as [this code page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) is generally intended for Central or Eastern European languages that are written in the Latin script.

```
import pandas as pd
inflation_data_url = 'https://stat.gov.pl/download/gfx/portalinformacyjny/pl/defaultstronaopisowa/4741/1/1/miesieczne_wskazniki_cen_towarow_i_uslug_konsumpcyjnych_od_1982_roku.csv'
pd = pd.read_csv(inflation_data_url, sep=';', encoding="ISO-8859-2")
print(pd.head())                                                 #--- Here
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one also returns a mangled string "Wskaw i usług konsumpcyjnych"

Comment: @AleisterCrowley Because it is `Windows-1250`.